Is there a way to sort an array by the biggest number with a string next to it?
I don't know if it's possible. I've tried looking everywhere for an answer, but nothing. I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a list of the top YouTubers and sort it by subscribers.
const points = ["Apple - 40", "Orange - 80", "Lemon - 140"];

points.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

I tried doing this, however it didn't do anything. I want it to be sorted by the value at the end of each string, not by the first string.

Your comparison function always returns NaN...

What should the result be?  Is "L"emon before "O"range?  ie alphabetically?  Or ignore the letters and only use numbers.  What if you have "-40" instead of "- 40" - is that before 0?   What if you have ["Orange - 1", "Apple - 1"] which comes first?

@AlexanderNenashev nothing wrong with your answer, why delete it?   My comment was just tongue-in-cheek at the "best" performance comment.

This question is similar to: How to sort strings in JavaScript numerically. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your current sort() logic  is attempting to coerce the strings to numeric values. As they begin with alphabetic characters, that's not going to work as you expect.
To do what you require you need to manually extract the digits and sort those directly. There's a lot of ways to do this. In the example below I used a regex to remove anything that's not a digit, but other approaches may work better for the format of string available in your specific use case.


const points = ["Apple - 40", "Orange - 80", "Lemon - 140"];
const getNumber = str => +(str.replace(/^\D+/g, ''));

let sortedPoints = points.sort((a, b) => getNumber(b) - getNumber(a));
console.log(sortedPoints);




You can write a custom function for comparison like following
const points = ["Apple - 40", "Orange - 80", "Lemon - 140"];

points.sort(function(a, b){
    let numberA = a.split(' - ')[1];
    let numberB = b.split(' - ')[1];
    return numberB - numberA;
});

It gets the number from the string and compares them instead of comparing the whole string.
